# Using XPath to get the first child for every child of a node

Tags: html, xpath

I'm trying to parse some HTML with the following structure, how can I extract the first `<a>` element of every `<li>` element using xpath?

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a>
        <span>
        <a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>
        <span>
        <a>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Comment: Please show the XPath expressions you have tried and that did not give you the correct result.

Comment: @Mathias I've tried :

`//li//a` - Which returns the all the `<a>` nodes,

`(//li//a)[1]` - Which returns the first `<a>` of the first '<li>',

`(//li)[1]//a` - Which returns all the `<a>` nodes of the first `<li>`,

and `//li/a[1]` - Which didn't return anything.

Comment: If `//li/a[1]` does not return anything while `(//li//a)[1]` does, then the HTML sample you show is not representative for your actual document. Then, `a` would be a descendant of `li`, but not a direct child of it. Please show a more complete sample.

Comment: @Mathias : You are correct, I apologize. `//li/a[1]` did not work because it wasn't a direct child (there is an `article` tag in between, which I omitted for simplicity). When I correct the expression to be `//li/article/a[1]`, I get the first `a` for the first `li`. Does this make things clearer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> @Mathias : You are correct, I apologize. //li/a[1] did not work because it wasn't a direct child (there is an article tag in between, which I omitted for simplicity).

Then let me post this as a solution with some more explanation.

If, as you have described, `//li/a[1]` does not return anything while `(//li//a)[1]` does, then the HTML sample you show is not representative for your actual document. Then, `a` would be a descendant of `li`, but not a direct child of it.

A correct XPath expression in this case is

```
//li//a[1]
```

but only use it if the level of nesting varies, i.e. if there could be other elements nested between `li` and `a`:

```
<li>
  <article>
    <other>
      <a/>
```

If the nesting is consistent, but it is not always the `article` element which is in between `li` and `a` then use

```
//li/*/a[1]
```

Which avoids the `//` axis that is computationally more expensive than `/`.

Finally, if you know that the `a` elements you are interested in are always grandchildren of `li` elements and if it is always the `article` element in between them, use

```
//li/article/a[1]
```

---

> When I correct the expression to be //li/article/a[1]', I get the first a` for the first li.

`//li/article/a[1]` returns several results if there are several `a` elements that are children of `article` and grandchildren of `li`. If this only returns a single result either

- you invoke this XPath expression in a context where only a single result is expected, e.g. if you use an XPath library in a programming language or
- the structure of your input document is even more intricate

Answer (score 2):

I think that the XPath to accomplish that would be `.//ul/li/a[position()=1]` .

Explanation:

The reason I spell it all out as `.//ul/li/a` is because, when you use the xpath, if there is an error, your stack-trace will reveal exactly what the locator pointed at, and is less vague.  But, you can obviously short-hand it if you dont care: `.//a` .

Using the position clause, you can do `=1` or `>1` , or whatever. I would choose using `[position()=1]` over using `[1]` because Xpath doesn't use 0-based arrays, which might confuse others looking at your locator. I mean `position=0`, by logic, means null, right?

I start my locator with a `.` because personally, sometimes I like to chain my locators together in a combination.   You don't really need to start with the dot char but since i use the `//` wildcard in this case, its effectively the same as starting without a dot, but with the additional ability to be chained.

Answer tested on http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/

Comment: No, there is no need to start an XPath expression with `.` in this case and it would even be harmful if the context node is anything else than the document node. `(.//ul/li/a)[position()=1]` returns either 0 or 1 result nodes, which is clearly not what the OP wants, in my opinion. They want to select the first `a` element of every `li`, which is more than 1 result.

Comment: @MathiasMüller Yep, your totally right.  My locator was wrong.  I think I fixed it.

Comment: Thanks for editing your answer, but I still do not understand why starting the expression with `.` would facilitate chaining. Could you perhaps elaborate with an example? A path expression starting with `//` can easily be appended to another one.

Comment: Chaining in the context of using Selenium.